# JQUERY MOBILE Dialog instead of JS Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building my first JQ Mobile App and I have been trying to figure out a way to replace the Alert(MyResult) by a nicer JQMobile Modal pop up like the one here: [DIALOG](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/)

I Tried Pretty much everything but nothing works.

Technicaly in my Applications I have a 3 fields peple need to fill up, than I validate and run some calculations to display the result

I just a Button with an Onclick Funtion:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b" onclick="Calculer_BMI()">CALCULER</button></div>            
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b" onclick="Delete_fields()">EFFACER</button></div>            
    </div>
```

and my Function Calculer_BMI() lookes like this:

```
<script>
function Calculer_BMI(){

    var heightFeet   = parseInt($('#feetInput').val());
    var heightInches = parseInt($('#inchesInput').val());
    var weightPds    = parseFloat($('#weightInput').val()); 

    if ($.isNumeric(heightFeet) && $.isNumeric(heightInches) && $.isNumeric(weightPds) ){
        var result = ((weightPds / Math.pow((heightFeet * 12)+heightInches,2)) * 703).toFixed(2);
        alert("Votre IMC est: " +result);   


    }
    else
    {                       
    alert("Tous les champs sont obligatoires et doivent seulement contenir des chiffres.")
    }
}
```

I just that the Alert Really Sucks on iOS or any other Mobile Platform. I would like something nicer like this [Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVaiG.png)

And this is the Code provided on JQMobile Website for the dialog...and I tried 60.000 way to fire it up from my Onclick Function but it doest work.

```html
<a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">Delete page...</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
    <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anybody here have experience with Modals? I just need to display be able to build it and call it from my function in order to display the result calculated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Finally I think I just need to find a way to fire this simple line from my Function, without the Button Part `<a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">Delete page...</a>`

Comment: I figured it out....seem like the mind is more opened to coding in the morning. Just need to put my Pop Up in a Div like the exemple, and in My Function, I pass the resuts to a Div. I just can't believe I wrote such a long post for such an ez thing. `$('#resultContainer').html("<h1>" + result + "</h1>");  
   $("#popupDialog").popup('open');`